# I ran this function on PostgreSql and it stated that No function matches the given name and argument types. What should I do?

Tags: postgresql

SELECT make, SUM(price) FROM car;

No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Can you add the car table definition?
Probably, the field "price" is not of a type that can be used to sum.

Comment: Yea, I just discovered that the field price was actually needed to be converted to Numeric and I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the type of the field is correct, it has to be a numeric type ([postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-aggregate.html)).